# Simplify the changing of this binary variable

Tags: python

When I am writing my code, I find the following situation many times:

```
def Mwindow_stayontop(self, event):
    if CFG["AlwOnTop"] == 1:
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE)
        CFG["AlwOnTop"] = 0
    else:
        self.SetWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
        CFG["AlwOnTop"] = 1
```

Can anybody think of a simpler way of doing this? I tried to use SIN and COS to alternate the value between 0 and 1, but couldn't.

Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CFG["AlwOnTop"] = 1 - CFG["AlwOnTop"]
```

or

```
CFG["AlwOnTop"] = not CFG["AlwOnTop"]
```

The complete function could be:

```
def Mwindow_stayontop(self, event):
    CFG["AlwOnTop"] = 1 - CFG["AlwOnTop"]
    self.SetWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | CFG["AlwOnTop"]*wx.STAY_ON_TOP)
```

though some might consider that too compacted.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a short version:

```
def Mwindow_stayontop(self, event):
    CFG["AlwOnTop"] = not CFG["AlwOnTop"]
    self.setWindowStyle(wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE | 
                        (wx.STAY_ON_TOP if CFG["AlwOnTop"] else 0))
```

If you want to consider the AlwOnTop as a boolean property, you can use the fact that 0 is False and 1 is True to your advantage. `not` will alternate the states.